# The content and its scrollbar

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

A html like this(css: width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;):

[image]

As we all know that when we drag the scrollbar and the content will scroll up and down.

The question is: I don't want the content scroll up or down when dragging the scrollbar(because I want the content scroll under my rules when dragging the scrollbar.), can I resolve this problem by using javscript?

Comment: why not removing the scrollbar via css ?

Comment: if you don't want the content scrolling up and down when dragging, why do you want a scrollbar in the first place?

Comment: @VincentHogendoorn Because I want the content scroll under my rules when dragging the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: hidden` rule to the container of the text

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transparent div over your scrollbar. That should prevent it from being draggable, but still allow the content to scroll via keyboard interaction.

Comment: Your solution can make it. And I have a solution is that I put a new brother div after the content div, add 'overflow: hidden' to the content div, and change the height of the new div so I can simulate a new scrollbar to control the content.

Answer (score 0):

In css only overflow hidden can make it

```
overflow: hidden
```